# How can i prevent the password prompt in Firefox for allowed subfolder with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

The main directory of an apache web server is protected via .htaccess.
The `subfolder` is excluded from password protection.

When i open the path to the `subfolder` in Chome, everything works well.

When i open the path to the `subfolder` in Firefox, the site is loaded in background and the password prompt appears. I first have the cancel this password prompt, bevor i can use the website in this `subfolder`.

Why does this happen? And how can i prevent the apperence of this prompt in Firefox? Whats the difference to the Chrome browser?

I already tried to use an extra .htaccess file in this subfolder with
`Satisfy Any`, but the behavior is the same.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Type password"
AuthUserFile "*path to file*"
require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/subfolder/#
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be caused by some content which is loaded from the main directory or any other protected location. Most likely this will be the `favicon.ico`. The web browser tries to download this file automatically from the root.

My guess is that while chrome ignores the `HTTP 401` error it gets, firefox asks the user for the credentials. Because this is not essential for the web page to operate you can fully use the site after dismissing the prompt.

To solve this just add `favicon.ico` to the unprotected files in your `.htaccess`: